# How to refresh the database MySQL inside laravel and PHP project?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have create a tables name `country_packages` inside MySQL workbench. Then I make migration inside PHP Laravel project. By using following command:

```
$ php artisan migrate
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't create the tables of `country_packages`. I already force to make migrate. But still the new table doesn't created inside Laravel. What's wrong actually?

Comment: It should work, unless your migration file isn't done correctly. You can do `php artisan migrate:rollback` to rollback the last migration, then double-check your file.

Comment: I already tried your solution but it's not work. I dont know why.

Comment: Can you show your `country_packages` table`s migration file?

Comment: did you tried: `php artisan migrate:fresh` ?@azim

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh.....

Comment: @mare96 I've tried but still doesn't create the tables

Comment: @azim Have you already created `country_packages` table manually?

Comment: can you show the migration file?

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... yup, I actually dump the database inside the MySQL Workbench. After that, I migrate the laravel using artisan command. But, the table of country_packages doesn't create. How do I show you the migration file? Am sorry, am a beginner actually

Comment: @KayoBruno how do I list out the migration file? is there any command?

Comment: @azim `php artisan migrate` command will only create table if you have created migration file for that particular table. You should go through this once https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations

Comment: okay.. how to create migration file for that particular table? @PrashantDeshmukh..... thanks alot. you really help me. You are my sifu now! Yes Sir! :)

Comment: @azim `php artisan make:migration create_country_packages`

Answer (score 0):

### -- Table structure for table `country_packages`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `country_packages`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `country_packages` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `package_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2412 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `country_packages`

LOCK TABLES `country_packages` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `country_packages` DISABLE KEYS */;

here's I successfully created table country_packages inside MySQL

Comment: You need to add this to your question by clicking on the Edit button, not as an answer.